Does NTTP construction always happen for CTAD even if value of type of that specialization is given?
This is (partially) reduced from CTAD instantiates other specialization when explicit argument is given.
https://godbolt.org/z/5To7nKEP3
template<int N>
struct Bar {
    int n = N;
    constexpr Bar() {}
    constexpr Bar(const Bar& b): n{b.n - 1} {}
};

template<Bar b> constexpr int get_n() { return b.n; }

constexpr auto b = Bar<1>{};
static_assert(b.n == 1);

#ifdef _MSC_VER
static_assert(get_n<b>() == 1);
#else
static_assert(get_n<b>() == 0);
#endif

Clang and GCC seems always invoke and deduce from Bar's constructor(s) to determine the real template argument even if the given argument is of type of specialization of Bar, which MSVC doesn't agree.
What does the standard say?

Reduced examples can be posted in the same question instead of creating a new question for each reduced example. You can even replace the old question with the reduced example.

@user12002570 This question is only part of the other question and it is complete on its own. IMO in this particular case a new question is suitable for focus and SEO.

As long as the same answer/explanation applies to both, we have the same basic question.

I disagree "the same answer/explanation applies to both" in this case. Answer of the other question may reference this , but people may answer this one independently without addressing possible complicated issues of the other one.

So as long as this is a subset/subpart of the other, they're a dupe. The questions don't have to be an exact copy of the other to be a dupe. People can create any number of reduced examples from the original. That doesn't mean that the questions are different.

I'd agree only if the other one has answer. Closing before that stops people from answering only this one.

That isn't a good logic. As per that logic, users can/should replicate their questions as many times as they want until they have the answer to the original/first question. The point of closing as a dupe is that(among other things), people can/should post their answer in the original dupe instead of the new one such that the explanation given in the original will explain the new post also.

@user12002570 I reopened the question, because it seems clear to me that, while the answer to this question will likely be relevant to an answer to the other question, the other question's main point will be unrelated to what is asked here. In the other question there is a problem of deciding whether or not the explicit-specifier needs to be checked and in which order this happens with template argument deduction. Here the question is about whether there are template parameter initialization rule exceptions when the argument is already of a type that is specialization of the class template.

And anyway, this more-focused question will likely be more helpful to other readers than a complex answer to a more complex question and that is ultimately the goal.

The program should be ill-formed for either of the static_asserts.
First, note that this has nothing to do with CTAD. If you explicitly specify Bar<1> as template parameter type, you still get the same compiler behavior.
Class template argument deduction is always done and will deduce Bar<1> here.
However, the question is now how the template parameter object is initialized from the template argument to determine the relevant specialization of get_n that will be called.
How exactly this is supposed to happen for class types was underspecified, see CWG issue 2459. I guess this is why you see compiler divergence in your example.
The resolution of the issue with paper P2308R1 at the end of 2023 makes it so that the call get_n<b>() will be ill-formed.
Basically, the new rules state, applied to your example, that we start by imagining a variable defined as
constexpr Bar<1> v = b;

And then we further imagine that the template parameter object (also of type Bar<1> as deduced earlier) is copy-initialized from the expression v. If then the the template parameter object is not template-argument-equivalent to v (i.e. they have the "same" value (and type)), then the program is ill-formed.
That happens in your case, because the copy constructor (which is used in the initialization of v and in the copy-initialization of the template parameter object) will produce a different value in the new object than in the source object.
It seems that none of the compilers have implemented that yet.

So IIUC two initializations(for v and the template parameter P) are performed regardless of type of b and replacing b.n - 1 with b.n ^ (b.n & 1)(https://godbolt.org/z/5oYjh1G66)  would be well-formed if P2308R1 is implemented?

@VainMan I think so and then 0 would be the correct result.
